# Is it possible to pull BOOT0 HIGH for this Nucleo 32 board?

Tags: stm32, schematics

I have an [STM32F303K8](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um1956-stm32-nucleo32-boards-mb1180-stmicroelectronics.pdf) Nucleo board. By removing jumper SB9 I can power it eternally by 5V pin. And the USB is not and will not be connected. So I don't want to use the boards built in ST-LINK.

I have an 3.3V FTDI to UART adapter and I wanted to try flashing the MCU via its UART protocol. But the CubeProgrammer gives error.

My problem is that it seems I need to pull BOOT0 pin to HIGH but from the schematic I couldn't find a way to do that. It seems there is no dedicated BOOT0 pin for this board.

[image]

I am also confused with the MCU diagram below:

[image]

My questions are:

1-) In my case SB12 and SB13 jumpers are connected. But look at pin 32 and 31 above. They are both labeled as PB8. Does that mean pin 31 and 32 of the MCU is internally connected?

2-) Is it really impossible to pull BOOT0 pin HIGH by not touching the MCU pins directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Justme that soldering a wire to SB12 is the simplest way to do this.

However you should keep in mind that **system bootloader actually samples tree different interfaces** - USART1 (PA9/PA10), USART2 (PA2/PA3) and I2C1 (PB6/PB7) on STM32F303x6/8 devices. This means that it is possible for it to activate on a wrong port, depending on what your have connected to those pins.

For the sake of completeness I'd like to present another possible [and way more cumbersome] solution.

You can embed UART bootloader into your code and trigger it by any free pin. This has an obvious advantage of using existing board connector without any soldering. And not so obvious advantage of bootloader only listening on a specific port that you dedicate for firmware updates.

There are many bootloader sources available on the web, including I believe from STM itself. You'd need to add it to your code and make changes necessary for activation. Then you flash it into main memory using STLink. After that you can deactivate STLink and use FTDI dongle for future updates.

A variation on this approach is to make a [long jump](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00000BLufdSAD/how-do-i-jump-from-application-code-to-bootloader-without-toggling-the-boot0-pin-on-stm32h745) from your code into system bootloader, triggered by any free pin on a startup. You still have to be cautious of those three interfaces, but at least you won't have to bother with bootloader code and will save flash space. I think this approach might be even simpler than soldering a wire, if you are OK with some tricky programming.

Comment: This is very interesting if it works. I dont think I can code this myself though. You wrote "There are many bootloader sources available on the web," Could you add a link? I couldn't find any by googling.

Comment: @GNZ [X-CUBE-IAP-USART](https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/x-cube-iap-usart.html) is a good starting point. But if you don't feel like embedding the bootloader, check out the long jump option I've added to the answer. This may take only a few lines of code for pretty much the same result. You just have to place it at the very beginning of your program, before periphery initialization. You only need to test one GPIO to make a decision.

Comment: Hi again. I found some examples for long jump, tried it and it works. Really cool. In my situation I wont have access to USB and access to back side of the board SB12. So if I want to make update using on-board pins, the "long jump" seems the only solution. There is only one thing I need to be careful. If I upload a wrong code which doesn't include the same long jump and associated pin and reset, its point of no return.

Comment: @GNZ I am glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

1. The board is designed to take multiple different STM32 MCUs. They have different pinouts. You can check the exact pinout for the package from the datasheet, but suffice to say, on your MCU the pin 32 and 16 are grounds so these solder bridges must be closed, and the pin 31 is BOOT0 which also must have the solder bridge closed to have a pull-down connected.
2. Yes it is possible! But based on your previous question you likely can't use the methods. You could connect 3.3V momentarily to the SB12 or R21, but if you can't access them if they are on the bottom side then you need to momentarily apply 3.3V to pin 31 directly.

So it may be a fastest thing to solder a small wire to BOOT0 and 3V3 for a pushbutton.

Comment: Thank you just out of curiosity  I removed the board so I can access the bottom side for now and can try to apply 3.3V to SB12 tomorrow. I have an 3.3V FTDI to UART adapter and I will try flashing the MCU via its UART protocol. But when I do that should the 3.3V to SB12 be applied all the time before I connect to Cube Programmer? Could you write a few words about that procedure as well? I want to try and let you know.

Comment: @GNZ §3.5 of RM0316: "The values on both BOOT0 pin and nBOOT1 bit are latched on the 4th rising edge of SYSCLK after a reset"

Comment: @Maple Does that mean 1-) I should connect BOOT0 to 3.3V 2-) perform a reset and the MCU will be in boot mode to be able to flash code?

Comment: @GNZ Yes. Although I wouldn't call it "boot mode". It is a normal MCU mode, running code from system memory instead of main flash. It just so happens that the code in question is a bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

No need to be confused. That's because the STM32 is configured to execute an application from it's internal flash. That's why BOOT0 is pulled low. If it was pulled high, it would execute its internal bootloader code upon startup.

The main question here is: Why do you think that you need to pull this pin up?

Regarding the thing with touching the MCU pins: I guess that SB12 is a resistor. There's probably another resistor nearby which would pull that pin to VCC. But again: This would cause the STMs bootloader code to run and your application wouldn't start.

The pin naming of the schematic symbol is a bit misleading. According to the reference manual there is no pin PB8 for that package. It's the BOOT0 pin and nothing else. Pin32 is VSS. It's possible there is a similar package where the pinout might differ here but your first reference has always to be the reference manual or datasheet, not a schematic symbol from a schematic.

Comment: Why need to pull BOOT0 up? As explained in the question, to go into the bootloader, to program the MCU via the bootloader.